# Can we have 'routes' to controller's class methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If '**is_name_available**' is a class method in my **'registrations'** controller, can we have a route for it in routes.rb ?

If yes, what is the syntax ?

In routes.rb, I currently have the following 
(which is giving me an error - The action 'is_name_available' could not be found for RegistrationsController)

```
get 'is_name_available', :to => 'registrations#is_name_available'
```

Comment: Why not make it instance method?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I am trying to find out if we can or cannot do this. And if we cannot, the reasons why we cannot.

Comment: No, you can't. Because that's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. The whole Rails routing framework is based on controller and action. Action necessarily has to be a instance method.